# I've got this error : Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: javascript, express, ccxt

I've got this error:

```
Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

I use ccxt and express. I think its express the problem but I don't know what to do.

```
'use strict';
import { response } from 'express';

const api = () => {
const ccxt = require ('ccxt');
let sum = 0;
let i = 0;
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

// Defining CORS
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "X-Requested-With,content-type"
    );
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
      "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
    );
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    next();
});

...
```

Comment: The error certainly doesn't occur in the code you pasted here. You should share the actual stacktrace and related code. Also, why mix ECMAScript module imports and CommonJS imports (`import` and `require`)?

Comment: Where does that error show up? Do you have a stack trace? Any leads to what code causes it? Any [mcve]?

Comment: the error is in the response file:

var res = Object.create (http.ServerResponse.prototype)